# Unable to display "Hello World" from custom module

Tags: module, magento-1, extensions

I am following the book: Getting Started with Magento Extension Development. And I'm unable to make my extension echoing "Hello World".

I believed there are 3 area I need to take care:

1. active the module from `app/etc/modules/Froggyline_HappyHour.xml`.
2. > File: app/code/community/Froggyline/HappyHour/etc/config.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Froggyline_HappyHour>
               <version>0.0.0</version>
           </Froggyline_HappyHour>
       </modules>
       <frontend>
           <routers>
               <froggyline_happyhour>
                   <use>standard</use>
                   <args>
                       <module>Froggyline_Happyhour</module>
                       <frontName>happyhour</frontName>
                   </args>
               </froggyline_happyhour>
           </routers>
       </frontend>
   </config>
   ```
3. > FILE: app/code/community/Froggyline/HappyHour/controller/GreetingController.php

   ```
   <?php
   class Froggyline_HappyHour_GreetingController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
   {
       public function helloWorldAction()
       {
           echo 'Hello World';
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

I am visiting the following URL: `http://localhost/happyhour/greeting/helloWorld` and receive `Http 404`.

Which step did I miss, so that the page will display "Hello World"?

Comment: Apparently, there was has a typo in the [Official book](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf), `controller` suppose to be `controllers`... Just wasted my day debugging this... Disapointed with the official book. I will give credit to this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/68571/26421

Comment: see at http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

Comment: Please Note about the [Errata of the book](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/support/14239)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is test and working

**app/etc/modules/Froggyline_HappyHour.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Froggyline_HappyHour>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
    </Froggyline_HappyHour>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/community/Froggyline/HappyHour/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Froggyline_HappyHour>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
    </Froggyline_HappyHour>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <happyhour>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Froggyline_HappyHour</module>
            <frontName>happyhour</frontName>
          </args>
      </happyhour>
    </routers>

  </frontend>

</config>
```

missing the controllers folder (s)
**app/code/community/Froggyline/HappyHour/controllers/GreetingController.php**

```
<?php
class Froggyline_HappyHour_GreetingController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function HelloWorldAction() {

     echo "hello world"; exit;

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, damn.... This book just waste my whole day debugging. It is written `controller` which supposed to be `controllers`. You just saved my life.... Thank you.. :)

Comment: I'm referring to 2 books, I just mixed up with another book called ["Magento Extension Developers Guide Guide v1.0"](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf). The typo is actually in this official book instead and not the book I mentioned in my original question.

Comment: controller is used but for something else

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. anyway, thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the version number in the `config.xml` matches the `app/etc/modules/Froggyline_HappyHour.xml`

Also, I've never seen a version 0.0.0.  Try making it 0.1.0

Comment: This didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Glad it worked at last. Don't forget to review all the file names as well...

Everything on the book is alright except in this file:

`app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/etc/ config.xml`

Where you have to replace

```
<routers>
  <foggyline_happyhour>
  ...
  <foggyline_happyhour>
<routers>
```

by

```
<routers>
  <happyhour>
  ...
  <happyhour>
<routers>
```