# Auto-changing the “Stock Availability” from “Out of Stock” to “In Stock” on quantity change

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, out-of-stock, stock-status

assume the product quantity is "0", once we edit the quantity to "1". again we have to change from

"out of stock" to " in stock" to buy in site

So I’ve been looking for a way to change the Stock Availability back to In Stock when the quantity field is greater than 0.

here someone posted solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168295/magento-auto-changing-the-stock-availability-from-out-of-stock-to-in-stock

we can use Magento event catalog_product_save_after. Create an observer method that does the following on event catalog_product_save_after.

can anyone please explain me in detail what and all needs to be done for this. means in which file which code we have to add ?

```
public function catalog_product_save_after($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $stockData = $product->getStockData();

    if ( $product && $stockData['qty'] ) {
        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getEntityId()); // Load the stock for this product
        $stock->setData('is_in_stock', 1); // Set the Product to InStock                               
        $stock->save(); // Save
    }
}
```

**as Qaisar Satti said i am trying this :**

**app/etc/modules/Froggyline_HappyHour.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Froggyline_HappyHour>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
    </Froggyline_HappyHour>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/community/Froggyline/HappyHour/etc/config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Froggyline_HappyHour>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
    </Froggyline_HappyHour>
  </modules>
  <adminhtml>  
        <events>

                <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
                    <observers>
                        <happyhour>
                            <type>model</type>
                            <class>happyhour/observer</class>
                            <method>product_save_after</method>
                        </happyhour>
                    </observers>
                </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml> 

</config>
```

**app/code/community/Froggyline/HappyHour/Model/Observer.php**

```
 <?php
class Froggyline_HappyHour_Model_Observer {
public function product_save_after($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $stockData = $product->getStockData();

    if ( $product && $stockData['qty'] ) {
        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getEntityId()); // Load the stock for this product
        $stock->setData('is_in_stock', 1); // Set the Product to InStock                               
        $stock->save(); // Save
    }
}}

?>
```

Comment: do you have module related to product to install in magento?

Comment: sorry, i dont have such kind of module.

Comment: are this related to market place?

Comment: actually yes, but first please help me to solve for normal magento backend. as code is inter dependent, it may work for marketplace ....

Comment: follow this code and create a module when u finish with that tell i will add tell how you will do that..this is simple module. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68567/unable-to-display-hello-world-from-custom-module/68571#68571

Comment: okay, i will try.....

Comment: if anyone want easy solution , they can check here : https://github.com/mobweb/MobWeb_UpdateStockStatus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

Add this in `config.xml`

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Froggyline_HappyHour>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
    </Froggyline_HappyHour>
  </modules>
  <adminhtml>  
        <events>
     //second event
               <catalog_product_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <happyhour>
                            <type>model</type>
                            <class>happyhour/observer</class>
                            <method>product_save_after</method>
                        </happyhour>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml> 

</config>
```

`app/code/community/Froggyline/HappyHour/Model/Observer.php`

```
   <?php
class Froggyline_HappyHour_Model_Observer {
public function product_save_after($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $stockData = $product->getStockData();

    if ( $product && $stockData['qty'] ) {
        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getEntityId()); // Load the stock for this product use for 
        $stock->setData('is_in_stock', 1); // Set the Product to InStock                               
        $stock->save(); // Save use for 
    }
}
 }
```

### Solution 2 ([Not Tested, But Better Solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/145555/3535))

Add this in `config.xml`

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Froggyline_HappyHour>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
    </Froggyline_HappyHour>
  </modules>
  <adminhtml>  
        <events>
     //second event
               <catalog_product_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <happyhour>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>happyhour/observer</class>
                        <method>product_prepare_save</method>
                    </happyhour>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_prepare_save>
        </events>
    </adminhtml> 

</config>
```

`app/code/community/Froggyline/HappyHour/Model/Observer.php`

```
   <?php
class Froggyline_HappyHour_Model_Observer {

public function product_prepare_save($observer) {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $stockData = $product->getStockData();

        if ( $product && $stockData['qty'] ) {

            $stockData->setData('is_in_stock', 1); // Set the Product to InStock                               

        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: i tried your solution, but its working only after editing second time.

assume one product have "0" quantity. in site its displaying as " out of stock "

i updated the quantity to "1". it updated in backend. but still its displaying " out of stock "

in frontned. once i edit again, second time if i edit, than it will display

"in-stock" in frontend.

Comment: it is related to cache also i think.

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168295/magento-auto-changing-the-stock-availability-from-out-of-stock-to-in-stock in question only he gave one answer, when i tried that also , i need to edit 2 times to display that product as in stock in site...

Comment: i disabled the cache....

Comment: remove the `<adminhtml>`  tag and put inside the `<global></global>` tag

Comment: i tried , same result.... second time, if we click on "save " button , than only its displaying " in stock" in frontend

Comment: sorry, i fogot to remove the old code, that was overriding your new module. now seems i done something wrong, your module is not working.

Comment: below <config> text, i added your code in config.xml file

Comment: now add it inside the <global></global> tag

Comment: yes, i will try that.....

Comment: change the event update the code and try and feedback

Comment: i checked in all possible way.... its not working.....

Comment: did you change the event? and add as previous code

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: i did't got about change the event? and adding previous code

Comment: update the answer there were mistake in your config.xml

Comment: sorry, i updatede the new config.xml , but its not changing to in stock

Comment: did you update the observer file too?

Comment: yes, i updated just now.....

Comment: use <adminhtml> tag instead of global..

Comment: sorry, same result....

Comment: did modle updating in adminside?

Comment: in admin panel , it did't worked.. did he means?

Comment: change to old event and check.. catalog_product_save_after

Comment: please post  the old event....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31507/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-2-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: it is better to use `catalog_product_prepare_save` in this case, because it is a dedicated event for catalog product edit action from admin side. It would be nice if you can update your answer with this information.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy as you command boss :)

Comment: @QaisarSatti http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/145555/3535 see this answer. I hope you get me.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy totally understand it thanks for sharing :) updated the answer too.

Comment: @QaisarSatti I didnt test this code anyways :) Hopes it will work

Comment: @RajeevKTomy added the both solutions hope it will work..

Comment: @QaisarSatti Thanks man. I edited your answer to emphasise both solutions

Answer (score 1):

I write here only the main steps

1) write a custom module skeleton
you can use several "module creators" I personally use this
http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

You can set you company and module name and live all other options to NO to create a skeleton module

2) open etc/config and add you Model Name class, end declare the event observers you need

```
  <global>
    <models>
        <moduloname>
            <class>company_modulo_Model</class>
        </moduloname>
    </models>
    <events>
       < catalog_product_save_after>
        <observers>
            <moduloname>
                <class>moduloname/observer</class>
                <method>yourFunc</method>
            </moduloname>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_after>
```

3) create Model/Observer.php and write yourFun inside

```
    <?php  
    class company_Modulo_Model_Observer
{

    public function yourFunc(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    }
 }
```

For deeper details in the above steps there are tons of other resources, the above is only a sketch of what you have to do

hope it helps

Comment: "modulo" is italian's form of "module" sorry for the typo

Comment: okay, i i will try this......

Comment: you're welcome !

Answer (score 0):

In app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml
**I have changed this:**

```
<?php foreach($this->getStockOption()as $option):?>
<?php $_selected =($option['value']== $this->getFieldValue('is_in_stock'))?'selected="selected"':''?>
<option value="<?php echo $option['value']?>" <?php echo $_selected ?>>
<?php echo $option['label']?></option><?php endforeach;?>
```

**To this:**

```
<?php if(($this->getFieldValue('qty')*1)>0):?>
<option selected="selected"value="1">In Stock</option><?php else:?>
<option selected="selected"value="0">Out of Stock</option><?php endif;?>
```